# sas adding a percent sign to the macro values to use in proc sql like statement

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I basically have codes similiar to this

```
V2566
T67879
F7899
78902
```

in a sas dataset. These values,I wanted to use to store in a macro.
with quotes I  write this code

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
SELECT quote(CODES,"'") 
INTO :CODES  separated by ", "
FROM CODES;
QUIT;
%put macro variable CODES:&CODES;
```

This just added quotes. how do I modify to get codes by adding a % before and after each of these values to use like any ('%V2566%','%T67879%','%F7899%','%78902%'). That could be used in the my quote as this.

```
proc sql;
....
select ... where CODES like any (&CODES).
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried data CODES;
set CODES;

call symput ('CODES',TRIM(RESOLVE('%&CODES%')));
run;
%put macro variableCODES:&CODES; this created several % before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the values in before using the `QUOTE()` function.

```
SELECT quote(cats('%',CODES,'%'),"'")
```

But you will need to use pass-through SQL to use `LIKE ANY`.

```
select * from connection to mydb
(... where CODES like any (&CODES) ... )
;
```

If you want to similate LIKE ANY functionality then perhaps you can add more code into the macro variable?

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
SELECT 'CODES LIKE '||quote(cats('%',CODES,'%'),"'") 
  INTO :where separated by " or "
  FROM CODES
;
create table want as 
  select ....
  where &where
;
quit;
```

Comment: I think the codegen would be more efficient as a CASE statement as the number of data rows and code rows increases.  SAS or evaluation does not shortcut, and thus would evaluate all like expressions when there is a match.  Of course, non-selection requires all expressions to be evaluated regardless.

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE ANY` is a Teradata construct, `Proc SQL` does not support that syntax.

If the matching criteria are already in a data set leave it there.  Use `EXISTS` clause in your sql.

For example:

```
data codes;
  length code $10;
  input code @@; datalines;
Ja To Tom ary
;

proc sql;
  create table matched_by_containing_code
  as select *
  from sashelp.class
  where exists (select * from codes where class.name contains trim(code))
  ;
quit;
```

Note: If you had a custom function named `ANY` defined the following would be syntactically correct but functionally wrong.

```
proc FCMP; ... function ANY ... ; 
proc sql;
  create table matched_by_containing_code
  as select *
  from sashelp.class
  where name like any ('%Ja%', '%To%', '%Tom%', '%ary%')
  ;
quit;
```

For the case of constructing a part of a pass through SQL connected to data base recognizing LIKE ANY, the list is constructed by tweaking the elements being single quoted

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
  SELECT quote(cats('%',CODE,'%'),"'") /* pre and post pend wildcards to the base code value */
  INTO :CODES  separated by ", "
  FROM CODES;
QUIT;
%put macro variable CODES:%superq(CODES);

Proc SQL;
  ... my pass through ...
    ... like any (&CODES.)
  ...
```

Comment: I proc SQL I am actually conecting to the teradata

Comment: @viji I think you're trying to say that you're using SQL Pass Through to connect directly to your DBMS?